# Updating Javascript object value gives null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, updating

I'm trying to add a 'views' number on my page by incrementing the value every time someone visits the page.

I have a object like this:

```
{
    _id: "55da051afe08e73168fc7aeb",
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUdM9vrCbow",
    title: "Django Unchained",
    embedUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eUdM9vrCbow",
    __v: 0,
    downvotes: 0,
    upvotes: 0,
    views: 0,
    created_on: "2015-08-24T13:37:33.951Z",
    desc: "With the help of his mentor, a slave-turned-bounty hunter sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal Mississippi plantation owner."
}
```

I'm retrieving this object via AngularJS's '.one()' method:

```
var movie = Movie.one($routeParams.id);
```

The goal is to increment this value. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
movie.views++;
movie.put();
```

But that doesn't work and just gives me a null value, while this does work:

```
movie.views = 10;
movie.put();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `movie.views = movie.views + 1;`

Comment: Is it possible that you're not actually retrieving anything in the `movie` object?  That would explain why direct assignment of a number works, but incrementing (a null) doesn't.

Comment: Try incrementing other variables of your `movie`, if that doesnt work too, movie doesnt get loaded so everything is undefined and incrementing doesnt work but setting it to 10 does.

Comment: Wait, that's an object from some database, not a plain JS one, right? Which DB (wrapper) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can't increment a `null` value, set it 0 (zero) by default.

```
{
    _id: "55da051afe08e73168fc7aeb",
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUdM9vrCbow",
    title: "Django Unchained",
    embedUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eUdM9vrCbow",
    __v: 0,
    downvotes: 0,
    upvotes: 0,
    views: 0, //instead of 'null'
    created_on: "2015-08-24T13:37:33.951Z",
    desc: "With the help of his mentor, a slave-turned-bounty hunter sets out to rescue his wife from a brutal Mississippi plantation owner."
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the question. I actually set is to 0. I updated the question.

Comment: Oh ... when doing a `console.log(movie)` what do you have as result and what is the `views` value?

Comment: {
  "_id": "55da04e2fe08e73168fc7aea",
  "route": "movie",
  "reqParams": null,
  "restangularized": true,
  "fromServer": false,
  "parentResource": null,
  "restangularCollection": false
}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

I wasn't actually updating the actual object like [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024832/marc) suggested

```
Movie.one($routeParams.id).get().then(function(response){
    response.views++;
    $http.put("http://localhost:3000/movie/" + $routeParams.id, response);
});
```